# confirm password with lastpass

Tags: html, forms, passwords, lastpass

I have a form with two fields - "password" and "confirm (retype) password" and in addition, I have a weird bug with LastPass.
For each of these inputs, LastPass generates a new password
Maybe you know another way to prevent this and force LastPass to understand the situation with a repeating.
Or I should disable autocomplete for both inputs?

Comment: Could you please include your code?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary, there are just two inputs with type "password"

Comment: Please read [ask] @Ingrid - Yes, it is necessary to fully understand your implementation along with how best to solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just disable autocomplete of LastPass with

```html
data-lpignore="true"
```